# Unable to generate javadocs using frame with maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: maven-javadoc-plugin

I am using the default configuration of maven-javadoc-plugin 3.2.0
I would like to generate something like the the [testapidocs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin//testapidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html), but unfortunately it generates only NOFRAMES doc.
I tried playing a little bit with no success.
Anyone else having the same behaviour?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

this is the behaviour when you use Java 11. Changing it to Java 1.8 generates the frames. So I think it has been changed in the default doclet.